# Select first occurrences after NaNs in Numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am quite new to Python and Numpy. Can someone help me to understand how I can solve the problem here expose?
I have the following 2D array (arr) with NaNs and numbers, here below:

```
arr = np.array([[np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan],
             [np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, 3.4, np.nan, np.nan, 3.9]])
```

I need to obtain a new array (result) with first occurrences no-NaN of the second row in arr contidioned by first occurrences no-NaN of the first row in arr; the rest all NaNs. Below what should be the result:

```
result = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.9])
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, Your question is not clear. What do you mean by conditioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every first occurrence of a number in the second array after the occurrence of a num in the first array-

```py
import numpy as np

#arr = np.array([[np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan],
#                [np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, 3.4, np.nan, np.nan, 3.9]])

arr = np.array([[np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan],
                [3, np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, 3.4, np.nan, np.nan]])

result = np.full_like(arr[1, :], np.nan)

arr1pos = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(np.isfinite(arr[0, :])))
arr2pos = np.squeeze(np.argwhere(np.isfinite(arr[1, :])))

first_occurrence_idxs = np.searchsorted(arr2pos, arr1pos)
if first_occurrence_idxs[-1] == arr2pos.size:
    result[arr2pos[first_occurrence_idxs[:-1]]] = arr[1, :][arr2pos[first_occurrence_idxs[:-1]]]
else:
    result[arr2pos[first_occurrence_idxs]] = arr[1, :][arr2pos[first_occurrence_idxs]]
print(result)
```

```
[nan nan nan 3.1 nan nan nan]
```

Comment: Thanks for your promptly replay. The code works only in case of contiguous no NaNs values, but not if in the middle there are others values: here  below an example where it not work:
arr = np.array([[np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan],
                [3, np.nan, np.nan, 3.1, 3.4, np.nan, np.nan]])

Comment: I'm sorry, now even I'm confused. Could you figure out a better explanation of your problem and update the question? I would be glad to help

Comment: I need the first occurrences of number in my 2nd array based on the occurrences of number in first array.
In the specific, coming down the arrays first number occurrence on 1st array take first number occurrence on 2nd array. Repeat the step till to end of the arrays.
To take in consideration that both arrays are numbers and np.nans randomly. Many thanks for the support.

Comment: Sounds like you want the numbers in 2nd array to be aligned with the number occurrences in the first array, am I right?

Comment: Not to be aligned. In other words, for every occurrence of number in first  array I need to get the first occurrence of number (if present) in second array at index bigger of the number occurrence in first array.

Comment: okay, understood! let me try and find a solution

Comment: Great job! It works correctly. Many thanks